# How to draw square to tag on the image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image]

I'm building Tagging feature on photo like above using React Native (expo). Is there any such **Square Listener**?

Here is its essential Use Cases

1. User can change square size by dragging on their finger.
2. We can monitor square information including square width, height, x-coordinate, y-coordinate.

How can I achieve this? Do you have any idea or know any good library?

Any answer will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know of any library, but I think you're looking for `map` tag :) do comment if you find something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to want to use some sort of [face detection](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/advanced_facial_attributes_detection_addon), such as by cloudinary. There are other services too, such as [Google Face Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/face-tutorial) which might be even closer to what you're looking for. These services will just give you the initial coordinates of the face, leaving you to draw the box yourself. So you can roll your own "size by dragging" feature as well.